# GridBagLayout issues in JAVA

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I'm currently a novice in java and I'm looking for some help if you don't mind.
Beforehand, I'm sorry about the Google Drive links, my popularity didn't allow me to post pictures.

First of all, I know that other posts on this topic already exists but I didn't manage to find a proper answer.

My aim is to use a GridBagLayout to obtain something like this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxoqzZbxl2ZoVWpqSTB5cjJCdkE/view?usp=sharing

I use JLabel for the texts areas and the grid is a grid of JButton *(it's a 2 dimension table of JButton)*.

```
private String stateText = new String("STATE TEXT");
private String messageText = new String("MESSAGE TEXT");
BUTTONS = new JButton[3][3];
```

I created the **main container**, the **layout manager** and the **GridBagConstraints**:

```
JPanel content = new JPanel();
content.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,150));
content.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
```

Then I **initialized the gbc**:

```
gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 0;
```

And I began to **place the JLabels**:

```
stateField.setText(stateText);
stateField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
stateField.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.cyan));
//la taille en hauteur et en largeur
gbc.gridheight = 1;
gbc.gridwidth = 1;
content.add(stateField, gbc);

messageField.setText(messageText);
messageField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 100));
messageField.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.cyan));
gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 1;
gbc.gridwidth = 1;
gbc.gridheight = 2;
//Celle-ci indique que la cellule se réplique de façon verticale
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
content.add(messageField, gbc);
```

with messageText and stateText, **two Strings**.

My problem is that I used 2 'for' in order to place my BUTTONS[3][3] like this:

```
for(int i=1; i<4; i++)
for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
{

   gbc.gridy = j;
   gbc.gridx = i;

   gbc.gridheight=j+1;
   gbc.gridwidth=i+1;

   if(i==3)
    {
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
    }
    if(j==2)
    {
        gbc.gridheight = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
    }
    gbc.gridy = j-1;
    gbc.gridx = i-1;

    content.add(BUTTONS[i-1][j], gbc);
}
```

In the end, the result wasn't the one expected, indeed, the execution gave me this:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxoqzZbxl2ZoY3pRMVh1enVSWm8/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Could you please tell me where I'm wrong?
If there is a better way to do it?

Comment: A better way would be to use a [GUI builder.](https://netbeans.org/features/java/swing.html)

Comment: No, better would probably be to use MigLayout. Also, never set the sizes or preferredSizes of text components such as JTextAreas. Much better to set column and row properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a bug in this code:

```
gbc.gridy = j-1;
gbc.gridx = i-1;

content.add(BUTTONS[i-1][j], gbc);
```

gridy is getting set to -1 for some buttons. (whenever j = 0)

Also it is not clear to me whether you want the 3x3 buttons to form a grid of equal sizes or you want special sizes for some buttons.

If you want 3x3 buttons to be of same sizes. It will be simpler to construct another JPanel with GridLayout(3,3) where you add those buttons. Then you can add the new JPanel to your main panel in one shot.